# how does array.shape[:] works?

Tags: python, numpy

I think I am just confused with how **array.shape[]** works.
The output of **array.shape[:]** is the shape of the array in tuple which is fine.**output:(4,5)**
The output of **array.shape[1:]** is **(5,)** and the output of **array.shape[:1]** is **(4,)**.
I understand that it gives me the size of the columns and rows but why they both show up in the first element of the tuple? shouldn't be like **(5,) and (,4)**?
Also what does **array.shape[:2]** means that it gives me the size of the array but **array.shape[2:]** throw the "**not enough values to unpack**"?

[image]

Comment: `array.shape` is a `tuple`. That's like a list, but written with `()`.  A 1 term tuple is writen as `(2,)`.  `(,3)` is a syntax error.  You may need to study more basic python.

Comment: To further iterate what `hpaulj` wrote.  `array.shape` is just a tuple.  Everything that you're doing after that has absolutely nothing to do with arrays.  x[:1] gives you the first element of a tuple as a singleton tuple.  x[1:] gives you all but the first element of the tuple (which in this case also happens to be a singleton tuple.)

Comment: Also please never post code as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a problem with tuples here, not with `array.shape` in itself.
As pointed out in the comments, `x[:1]` gives you the first element of a tuple as a singleton tuple, because you are indexing "all" elements of the tuple up to the first (included).

Instead, `x[1:]` gives you all but the first element of the tuple (a singleton tuple again, if your array is 2D.

This also explain your error: `array.shape[2:]` has no such elements: dimentions are `(4,5)`: there is no element with index 2 (and surely nothing after that), so you can't unpack 0 values.

Comment: Thanks rikyeah but the answer is not clear to me. I am not sure what you mean by x[1:] gives you all but the first element or array.shape[2:] has no such element with index 2 !!!

Comment: Are you familiar with python indexing? slicing?

Comment: I got it. Thank you. I don't know why I was confused in the beginning. the shape is returning a tuple and shape[:2] is simply slicing the tuple to show index 0 and 1. I guess I didn't think that you can slice tuples too.

Comment: Can you mark the question as correct and vote it up?